# SpringMVC Unit testing - Service method is not called

Tags: spring, spring-security, mockito, junit4

When I run unit test on the controller by mocking the service bean, it looks like the service method is not called at all. Is this expected behvaior or am I missing something?

SearchController.java

```
@Controller
public class SearchController {

    @Autowired
    SearchService searchService;

    @RequestMapping(value="/search", method=RequestMethod.GET)
    public String showSearchPage(Model model){

        model.addAttribute("list", searchService.findAll());

        return "search";
    }

}
```

SearchControllerTest.java

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@WebAppConfiguration
@ContextConfiguration("file:src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/springapp-servlet.xml")
public class SearchControllerTest {

    @Autowired
    private WebApplicationContext webAppContext;

    private MockMvc mockMvc;

    private SearchService searchServiceMock;

    @Before
    public void setUp(){
        this.mockMvc = MockMvcBuilders.webAppContextSetup(this.webAppContext).build();

        this.searchServiceMock = Mockito.mock(SearchServiceImpl.class);
    }

    @Test
    public void testShowSearchPage() throws Exception{

        when(searchServiceMock.findAll())
        .thenReturn(Arrays.asList("abc", "acb", "123"));

        this.mockMvc.perform(get("/search.do"))
        .andExpect(status().isOk())
        .andExpect(view().name("search"))
        .andExpect(forwardedUrl("/WEB-INF/jsp/search.jsp"))
        .andExpect(model().attribute("list", hasSize(3)));

        verify(searchServiceMock, times(1)).findAll(); //this test is failing

        verifyNoMoreInteractions(searchServiceMock);
    }
}
```

When I run the test, it seems like findAll() method isn't getting called and it is throwing exception. **"Wanted but not invoked searchServiceImpl.findAll()"**

What mistake am I making here?

-------------Update------------------

SearchControllerTestNew.java

```
public class SearchControllerTestNew {

    @InjectMocks
    SearchController searchController;

    @Mock
    SearchService searchServiceMock;

    @Mock
    View mockView;

    MockMvc mockMvc;

    @Before
    public void setUp(){

        MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);

        mockMvc = MockMvcBuilders.standaloneSetup(searchController).setSingleView(mockView)
                .build();
    }

    @Test
    public void testShowSearchPage() throws Exception{



        when(searchServiceMock.findAll())
        .thenReturn(Arrays.asList("abc", "acb", "123"));


        this.mockMvc.perform(get("/search.do"))
        .andExpect(status().isOk())
        .andExpect(view().name("search"))
        .andExpect(model().attribute("list", hasSize(3)))
        .andExpect(forwardedUrl("/WEB-INF/jsp/search.jsp"));//this fails now

        verify(searchServiceMock, times(1)).findAll();

        verifyNoMoreInteractions(searchServiceMock);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `SearchController` will use the autowired `SearchService` (part of your application context) not your mock, notice you create a mock but you are not using it anywhere, instead you create a `MockMvc` based on your application context.

A solution would be, using a standalone setup which gives you full control over the instantiation and initialization of controllers and their dependencies:

```
@Before
public void setUp(){
  this.searchServiceMock = Mockito.mock(SearchServiceImpl.class);
  mockMvc = MockMvcBuilders.standaloneSetup(new SearchController(seachServiceMock))
    .setViewResolvers(viewResolver())
    .build();
}

private ViewResolver viewResolver() {
  InternalResourceViewResolver viewResolver = new InternalResourceViewResolver();

  viewResolver.setPrefix("/WEB-INF/jsp/");
  viewResolver.setSuffix(".jsp");

  return viewResolver;
}
```

I've omitted some MVC infrastructure configuration in this example check the [`MockMvcBuilder`](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/test/web/servlet/setup/MockMvcBuilders.html#standaloneSetup(java.lang.Object...)) documentation for further configuration.

Comment: But if use StandaloneSetup, then I'm losing the ability to test for forwardUrl. Please see the updated post for my latest test code.   Since the stand alone setup doesn't have the webapp context, the forwardUrl test is failing. - forwarded URL expected but was <null>

Comment: you need you pass your ViewResolver using the setViewResolvers method, I've edited the configuration with it

Comment: you are correct.. setting the view resolver to the standalone setup worked. thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Although you have mocked the `SearchService` it isn't injected to the controller (*at least not evident from code you shared*).

Thus the `verify(searchServiceMock, times(1)).findAll();` is bound to fail as it is indeed never invoked.

Take a look at [@InjectMock](http://docs.mockito.googlecode.com/hg/1.9.5/org/mockito/InjectMocks.html) how mocks are injected.

Also you need to add below LOCs for whole thing to work

**First** introduce a field

```
@InjectMocks
private SearchController controller;
```

**Second** in `setUp()` add

```
MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
this.mockMvc = MockMvcBuilders.standaloneSetup(controller).build();
```

Comment: If I use @InjectMock and create a StandaloneSetup, then I'm losing the ability to test for forwardUrl. Since the stand alone setup doesn't have the webapp context, the forwardUrl test is failing. - **forwarded URL expected but was <null>**

Comment: Set either [viewResolvers](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/test/web/servlet/setup/StandaloneMockMvcBuilder.html#setViewResolvers-org.springframework.web.servlet.ViewResolver...-) or [setSingleView](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/test/web/servlet/setup/StandaloneMockMvcBuilder.html#setSingleView-org.springframework.web.servlet.View-) itself

Answer (score 0):

You can use `@MockBean` for your mocks, then they will be injected to Context automatically.

Doc: https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#boot-features-testing-spring-boot-applications-mocking-beans